# .jar File can't find image file path

Tags: java, jar, path, executable-jar

I'm creating a simple program that I now want to export as a executable jar file. Everything works fine except the jar file can't find the image.

For creating the runnable JAR file I used the second option in Eclipse 2021-12 (Package required libraries into generated JAR). This seems to work well, because I only have the jar and no other folders I need to run the program.

My jar file structure looks like this:
jar_file/
├─ images/
│  ├─ frog.png

I've tried multiple ways of getting the image file.

This is how I define Icon:
`private static Image icon;`

### Using toURI() and toString()

`icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/frog.png").toURI().toString());`

**Eclipse**

This does not work in Eclipse.

Path Output: `file:/C:/Projekte/serviceticketapp/target/classes/images/frog.png`

**Jar File**

This does not work in the Jar File.

Path Output: `rsrc:images/frog.png`

### Using toExternalForm()

`icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/images/frog.png").toExternalForm());`

**Eclipse**

This does not work in Eclipse.

Path Output: `file:/C:/Projekte/serviceticketapp/target/classes/images/frog.png`

**Jar File**

This does not work in the Jar File.

Path Output: `rsrc:images/frog.png`

### Using File and toURI()

`File imageFile = new File(getClass().getResource("/images/frog.png").toURI());`
`icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());`

**Eclipse**

This works in Eclipse.

Path Output: `C:\Projekte\serviceticketapp\target\classes\images\frog.png`

**Jar File**

Throws error.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical`

### Summary

Above you can see all the ways I tried to get the image file. Only one works in Eclipse and none of them work in the jar file.

What am I doing wrong or how do I have to arrange the files in order for it to work in the jar file and in Eclipse.

Please ask if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not showing us how you define 'icon'. Most of your calls produce a `String` which is not going to do if for you. `ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/frog.png"));` should do it for you

Comment: @g00se I'm sorry I should have said that icon is an image. I edited the post.

Comment: What are you going to do with it?

Comment: @g00se I'm creating a SystemTray Icon with it: `trayIcon = new TrayIcon(icon, "Service Ticket App");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use imagio (`import javax.imageio.ImageIO`)

```
tIcon = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/frog.png"), "Service Ticket App");
```

Comment: I tried using this method. `trayIcon = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("/images/frog.png").toURI())), "Service Ticket App");`. The problem is that the .jar file throws the same URI is not hierarchical error. Eclipse works without any problems.

Comment: Use the code I posted. Images should be loaded as resources, not files: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse